# Pandas where does not work as I would expect from the workings of apply

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with some missing values, that I need to replace with other values from a different dataframe.

I can do this with apply, but it is very slow as there is a lot of data. I suspect that it is very slow, because apply loops over all the rows and has to perform the pd.isnull check in every function call.

As there are not that many NaN values I thought that maybe the pandas `where` function would be a faster alternative. However, this did not work as I thought it would work, considering how apply works.

I created a reduced example as below. (As you can see, the indices are not unique, but a group belonging to a key is relatively small in comparison with the whole dataset.):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['x', 'a', 10], ['x', 'b', np.nan], ['y', 'b', 20]], dtype=object), columns=['collection', 'subpart', 'freq']).set_index('collection')
df_other = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['x', 'a', 40], ['x', 'b', 30], ['x', 'c', 50]], dtype=object), columns=['collection', 'subpart', 'freq']).set_index('collection')

# This works, but is too slow:
df.freq = df.apply(lambda row: df_other.loc[row.name].pipe(lambda df: df[df.subpart == row.subpart]).freq.values[0] if pd.isnull(row.freq) else row.freq, axis=1)

# I hoped to optimize it like this, but throws error:
df.where(pd.isnull, lambda row: df_other.loc[row.name].pipe(lambda df: df[df.subpart == row.subpart]).freq.values[0], axis=1)
```

The last line of code here throws an "AttributeError 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'". Seems the 'axis' argument here has a different meaning than in `apply`.

So, my question is: Can I make pandas `where` as I intend to use it? With the same result as `apply`. I would also accept any solution that optimized what I try to do in other way.

PS. As the data from the different dataframes has a different shape I cannot use someting like `combine_first`

Comment: As an aside, it's generally not great to set a dataframe column using the `.` notation. I believe this will raise a warning in the future, but it can lead to issues. Better to use `df['freq'] = `

Comment: I’ll second what @ALollz said, _don’t do it_.

Comment: @ALollz Thanks for the tip. As a side note, you will get an warning when you set a column like that, that did not existed before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is `update`. We just need to add `subpart` to the Index so that's included in the alignment. As @DanielMesejo points out, we need to specify `overwrite=False` as to not change existing non-null data.

```
df = df.set_index('subpart', append=True)
df.update(df_other.set_index('subpart', append=True), overwrite=False)
df = df.reset_index('subpart')
```

Also with `.fillna` since we only need to fill missing values:

```
df = (df.set_index('subpart', append=True)
        .fillna(df_other.set_index('subpart', append=True))
        .reset_index('subpart'))
```

---

```
           subpart freq
collection             
x                a   10
x                b   30
y                b   20
```

Comment: why is the first row 40 while it's 10 in the original?

Comment: @DanielMesejo `df` can be duplicated on the index, but `df_other` cannot. It's ambiguous as to what should happen in that case, so generally I'd suggest dealing with that prior to update with some sort of `drop_duplicates`